# How to use ssh jenkins plugin in pipeline to remotely execute in the remote machine

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I used [ssh plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin?focusedCommentId=46335371) in Jenkins Job to ssh into a remote machine and run commands in that machine. I am trying to use the pipeline for Jenkins and I cannot find the script for the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not supported.

- `ssh-plugin` is not listed in the [pipeline compatibility list](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md).
- There is no reference to any workflow plugin inside the [ssh-plugin POM](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml), like in e.g. the [ssh-agent plugins POM](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-agent-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml).
- The [last release](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin?focusedCommentId=46335371) of `ssh-plugin` is Jan 8, 2014.

I'd conclude this plugin is abandoned. However there is some [commit activity](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-plugin/graphs/commit-activity). Consider writing an issue.

Comment: Do you have any other solution to solve my issue? other than calling the ssh command in every stage?

Comment: @ShakyaS You could e.g. try using shell scripts instead of ssh'ing for each command.